# SightCall iOS SDK incoming call event not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

**The issue we are facing implementing “SighCall” in IOS SDK**

We are implement one-to-one video calling functionality of SightCall inside our application(IOS SDK) . We have done the following thing in our application, they are as follows:

1) Added Voice over IP  in Background Modes section of the Capabilities tab.

2) Added our application id as :  myAppId

3) User Authentication and Connection establish successfully with received token.

**These are the issues:**

1) No incoming alert fired when receive call by other user.

2) Camera events are not working (incoming and outgoing video not work)

3) Do i need to do any special setting that i might be missing ?

Comment: Have you followed the directions given here https://docs.sightcall.com/gd/client-sdks/ios-sdk/. You must be testing this on real device right? Also make sure you add all the required frameworks.

Comment: Make sure to connect all required IBOutlet as well as assign and implement required delegates in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I have added all required frameworks and delegates too. Testing on real device